# get levels of factor from dataframe as integers

Tags: r

Given [this](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/12-supp-factors/), I know that:

Factors are stored as integers, and have labels associated with these unique integers.

Given this:

```
gender <- factor(c("male", "female", "female", "male"))
```

I can obtain the levels like this:

```
levels(gender)
"female" "male"
```

and I can do:

```
as.numeric(gender)
2 1 1 2
```

to transform the vector to a numeric vector.

The question I have, how can I obtain the integers of the levels purely based on a data frame's meta data? Taking gender as an example:

```
df <- data.frame(gender = "male")
df$gender <- factor(as.character(df$gender), ordered = FALSE, levels = c(
        "female"
        , "male"
    ))
```

How could I obtain **all** integers of the levels of this dataframe, which has only one row?

Comment: Maybe `seq_len(nlevels(gender))` or `unique(unclass(gender))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `seq_len` on `nlevels`

```
seq_len(nlevels(gender))
#[1] 1 2
```

or `unique` of the integers returned with `unclass`

```
unique(unclass(gender))
#[1] 2 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq_along` on the `levels` of `factor` :

```
seq_along(levels(df$gender))
#[1] 1 2
```